# What word describes someone who offers unsolicited advice?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

What word describes someone who offers unsolicited advice?

For example I might write:

> "At the risk of being called a [..........], I will offer you some unsolicited advice."

Comment: Not really serious, but how about mother-in-law? More seriously, I've never heard anyone say that they were going to offer unsolicited advice. In fact people who are inclined to offer unsolicited advice often do not realize they are doing so.

Comment: @DanielCook -- I know you didn't ask, but I think you might be mistaken.

Comment: It's actually not uncommon to say "dispenser/purveyor of unsolicited advice".

Comment: I wonder if the German word "Besserwisser" is ever used in English? It's been imported into some other languages, such as Swedish, and I think it would fit well here.

Answer (score 17):

[Busybody](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busybody) would work well here.

> that busybody across the street is always telling me how to tend to my own garden

Comment: *Busybody* seems to mean a person who pries (inquires into other people's business), rather than a person who gives advice without being asked.

Comment: Certainly in the UK, I know the usage to be for both scenarios.

Answer (score 17):

I have also heard this as being a *kibitzer*

> [***kibitz***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kibitz):  To look on and offer unwanted, usually meddlesome advice to others.

Comment: I like [this definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kibitzer) even more: one who looks on and often offers unwanted advice or comment <a kibitzer at a card game>; broadly : one who offers opinions

Comment: I don't see why... I listed that definition in my comment. The definition you'd already listed is also good.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest, [backseat driver](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/back-seat-driver):

> noun
>
> (informal)
>
> 1. a passenger in a car who offers unwanted advice to the driver
> 2. *a person who offers advice on or tries to direct matters that are not his or her concern*

The word *kibitzer* suggested by others is also a good one. But, I've not heard it used in this sense outside of card games.

Comment: Kibitzer is any heckler anywhere for any reason. Unwanted 'support'.

Answer (score 5):

You could humorously refer to yourself as a [*buttinsky* (sometimes spelled *buttinski*).](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/buttinski)

It is defined as:

> a meddler who tends to butt in

Or try: [*quidnunc*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/quidnunc). It has the advantage of being fun to say. It means:

> a nosy person; a busybody; a person who meddles in the affairs of others

I think offering unsolicited advice fits in the category of meddling.

Comment: To me, a _quidnunc_ is more someone who’s overly curious about what others are doing—not someone who gives opinions. It’s basically just someone who’s nosy. ‘Meddling’ in the _quidnunc_ context to me means just prying, not actively trying to influence.

Answer (score 5):

A *kibitzer* is a legitimate spectator giving unwelcome advice; a *buttinski* interferes in matters that are none of her concern; a *busybody* might neither interfere nor give advice, but will snoop and gossip to third parties.

Comment: And a *know-it-all* (one word?) is a conceited person who imparts the correct way to do something, or other information, with a sense of smug superiority. No need to thank me, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

[Yenta](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yenta)—Yiddish for *chronic intermeddler* and *one that meddles*

Comment: Yes, but more literally, a yenta is a gossip.

Answer (score 2):

[***smarty-pants***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smarty-pants)

> smarty-pants: a person who talks and behaves like someone who knows everything

[***smart aleck***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smart+aleck)

> smart aleck: an obnoxiously and self-assertive person with pretensions to smartness and cleverness

[***wisenheimer***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smart+aleck)

> wisenheimer: a wiseacre; smart aleck

[***wise guy; wiseacre***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Wise+guy?s=t)

> wise guy: a cocksure, conceited, and often insolent person; smart aleck

[***know-it-all***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/know-it-all)

> know-it-all: a person that acts as though they had better knowledge or understanding than anyone else

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest **[meddler](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/meddler)**.

From The Free Dictionary, *to meddle* is:

> 1. To intrude into other people's affairs or business; interfere. See Synonyms at interfere.
> 2. To handle something idly or ignorantly; tamper.

A person that feels the need to control or influence other people's lives can be called a meddler.  I think unsolicited advice fits in perfectly with this definition.