# A term for when people insist on giving you help you didn't ask for?

Tags: terminology

People love to tell other people what to do. It may not be control, so much as trying to help, especially when you've asked for help directly. However, there's a difference between answering someone's question and answering while piling on recommendations the person didn't ask about, and this is what I'm seeking a term for. Advertising and marketing feel similar to me in this vein. In the worst cases this can be overzealous religious followers professing your damnation if you don't follow with them (I think in Christianity they call it "witnessing"). Any which way, it comes across to me as a form of unsolicited advice: I didn't ask for it, so I don't want it; I want to stay focused.

Is there a better term for this than "unsolicited advice"? Also, is there a term for a person who exhibits this kind of behavior frequently?

Comment: “Unsolicited advice” is a great way to phrase this. I think you should stick with that. It’s a great turn of phrase on your part.

Comment: And see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79844/what-word-describes-someone-who-offers-unsolicited-advice for words for such people.

Comment: @NathanM. Much appreciated ☺ I needed something a bit less common / colloquial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through diving into the link supplied in the comments, and links thereafter, I have found [**officious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/officious):

> : volunteering one's services where they are neither asked nor needed 
>   : **meddlesome** • *officious* people who are always ready to offer unasked advice

Which leads me to define *unsolicited advice* as **officiousness**. I appreciate this in particular due to its uniqueness, which ensures people will come with less preconceived notions as to what this word means. Also, from the example supplied with the definition, I can see a person fond of officiousness being called **meddler**.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/officious_intermeddler#English supports this as well

Answer (score 2):

**nosey** and **busybody**. less formal, colloquial names for such person(s).

As in;

> *Nosey* and *busybody* are names for a person who people insist on giving
>   you help/advice you didn't ask for?

[nosy](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nosy)
[busybody](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/busybody)

Comment: Those are good suggestions but it is probably not clear to the OP what POS those are , how they fit in a sentence

Comment: @Mitch so edited

Comment: [Nosy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosy) is an adjective, busybody is a noun: "My aunt is so nosy ; she is such __a__ busybody"

Answer (score 0):

Two words that come to mind are:

enterprising:

> marked by aggressive ambition and energy and initiative

laborsaving:

> designed to replace or conserve human and especially manual labor

Comment: Giving excessive unsolicited advice doesn't save labour, if anything it slows the recipient down.