# What's the word for people who give an opinion unnecessarily?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for people who give an opinion unnecessarily; when it is not required or it's not their business or they are not asked to?

Can we call them 'critics'? Or loose tongued?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What word describes someone who offers unsolicited advice?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79844/what-word-describes-someone-who-offers-unsolicited-advice)

Comment: "Critics" would require a *negative* opinion.  It's possible for someone to endlessly evaluate things as good, bad, or neutral when no one wants to hear it.  Which do you want?

Answer (score -1):

I'd say busybody is the best word for this situation.

Comment: Please explain why you think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -2):

'critic'  'hyper-critical person' 'judger'  use whatever seems suitable...

Comment: Answers for word choice on EL&U are expected to include reasoning for your proposed selection, and, where possible, cited definitions and examples of usage in context.